# Webpack fails when run through npm run

Tags: json, node.js, ubuntu, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to setup React. When I try to run

```
npm run webpack -p
```

It gives the following error.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "webpack" "-i"
npm ERR! node v6.8.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! file /home/phani/test/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Trailing comma in object at 9:3
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! File: /home/phani/test/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/phani/test/npm-debug.log
```

And here is the error log,

```
   0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'webpack', '-i' ]
    2 info using npm@3.10.8
    3 info using node@v6.8.1
    4 verbose stack Error: Failed to parse json
    4 verbose stack Trailing comma in object at 9:3
    4 verbose stack   },
    4 verbose stack   ^
    4 verbose stack     at parseError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:390:11)
    4 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:79:23)
    4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:48:5
    4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    4 verbose stack     at tryToString (fs.js:455:3)
    4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:442:12)
    5 verbose cwd /home/phani/test
    6 error Linux 4.4.0-43-generic
    7 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "webpack" "-i"
    8 error node v6.8.1
    9 error npm  v3.10.8
    10 error file /home/phani/test/package.json
    11 error code EJSONPARSE
    12 error Failed to parse json
    12 error Trailing comma in object at 9:3
    12 error   },
    12 error   ^
    13 error File: /home/phani/test/package.json
    14 error Failed to parse package.json data.
    14 error package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
    14 error
    14 error This is not a bug in npm.
    14 error Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
    15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried installing webpack globally. Still the error persist.

Comment: Did you read the error message? "Tell the package author to fix their package.json file."

Comment: I was the one who setup package.json file. I was following tutorial instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Npm doesn't recognize `webpack` as it's one of the dependencies, and not an NPM script.

If you installed `webpack` locally (the preferred method) - In your `package.json` add a script:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "webpack -p"
}
```

Then run it using `npm run build`.

If you want to use the globally installed `webpack` - run it using `webpack -p` (without `npm run`).

Comment: "scripts": {
    "production": "webpack -p",
    
  },

Comment: The name doesn't matter. Have you installed NPM locally?

Comment: Yes. 
So I run webpack using  webpack -p (without npm run) and it solved the problem. But there were still some errors.

Comment: These are errors in your build / code. Good luck :)